# How to hook to desktop (leave in background) with electron?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

so I am working on a small feature. Basically, it adds a border to the desktop. So far, I got the design and everything down, but the two windows (two monitors) layer over everything else. So I can’t click anything on my computer because the borders (which have a transparent background) are over everything.

Example:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43588940/46045103-819c4480-c0d1-11e8-92ce-6c36b4ec6cc9.png

As you can see, the borders work but I can’t click anything on my desktop because it is blocking it.

So my question is, how can I link these borders to the desktop? Sort of like a desktop gadget. I just want it to stay in the background, so it isnt blocking all the computer functions.

Also, I can't click through the border because it is a transparent window and electron doesnt support clicking through transparent windows (feelsbadman). So I'm kinda screwed i just want borders on my desktop with this lol

My code:

````
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

let win

function runGouge() {

```
let displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays();
let externalDisplay = displays.find((display) => {
    return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0
})

win = new BrowserWindow({
    name: "Gouge4 ",
    width: 400,
    frame: false,
    toolbar: false,
    transparent: true,
    show: false,
    parent: "explorer.exe",
    x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
    y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50
})
win.setMenu(null);
//win.webContents.openDevTools();
win.maximize();
win.show();
win.loadFile('index.html');
win.setSkipTaskbar(true);
win.showInactive();
win.center();

win2 = new BrowserWindow({
    name: "Gouge2",
    frame: false,
    toolbar: false,
    transparent: true,
    show: false,
})
win2.setMenu(null);
//win2.webContents.openDevTools();
win2.setIgnoreMouseEvents;
win2.maximize();
win2.show();
win2.loadFile('index_blank.html');
win2.setSkipTaskbar(true);
win2.showInactive();
win2.center();
```

}

app.on('ready', runGouge);
````

Comment: I've just realized you do use `setIgnoreMouseEvents` (strange call though - if it's your _actual_ code). Dunno why it doesn't work for you, I can use it without issues with transparent window.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use HTML to generate the border? You can create 3 divs, position one to the bottom (`position: absolute; bottom: 0`), float one to the left (`float: left`) & one to the right (`float: right`).

The first div will have `background-color: purple`, and the other two will have a gradient `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), purple)`

This will ensure that the bounding boxes of all of these elements will be confined and won't interfere with your site's functionality. To overlay them all you just set the `z-index` to be higher than all the other elements in your site.

Comment: Because I want the borders to be on the desktop of their computer, not on top of their whole screen.

Comment: Then why not just assign a wallpaper?

Comment: Because its not dynamic..? tf

Comment: No need to be rude- the screenshot you provided in your question was of a border along the side of the screen. Either that or your choice of diction mislead me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable mouse events on your BrowserWindow with [`setIgnoreMouseEvents`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetignoremouseeventsignore-options). That means every event will be forwarded to the window behind that - won't block.

For example:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    focusable: false,
    transparent: true,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    fullscreen: true
  })
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'background-frame.html'))
  win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
})
```

<sub>I've chosen properties for BrowserWindow which I think fit a window you described but it's up to you</sub>